# Is there a way for me to see an ASP.NET website visually?

Tags: asp.net, graphics, sitemap

Basically, is there a tool out there that can analyze an entire ASP.NET solution and show me an architectural diagram similar to what can be created in Visio for the site, laying out a visual of the various references?

Comment: When I first read the question my initial response was 'Open your eyes'. But I agree with @milimetric that you should create a sitemap and visualize that.

Answer (score 0):

To start, I'm not sure why Visio can't do what you need.

1. You can generate a sitemap like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/12/02/432188.aspx
2. And then style it with some simple CSS to look however you like